# Scheduling a job on a certain date depending on data given

Tags: android, notifications, job-scheduling

**What I am trying to accomplish**

Get a date from Firebase Database and schedule a notification based on that date.

**What I tried**

I tried to use a service class that would start when the user is in the main activity and handle everything from the service class but it wouldn't send notifications if the service class didnt start again.

**What I know how to do**

I know how to get the date from the database, and I know how to create a notification already.

**What I need help with**

How to check database in the background to create a notification (probably through job scheduler) based on the date given from my database, even though the app is closed.

Comment: I believe if you want it to fire at a certain date or time then you need to use the AlarmManager API

Comment: What if I want it to check the database constantly to see if the date given matches the date today

Comment: Is this different functionality to the firing it at a certain time? If so, probably a periodic job scheduler

Comment: Oh no it's the same but I mean if a new date is added to the database I also want to send a notification when that date is todays date.